# How to show the complete text in the browser tab title

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Honeycrisp.jpg/800px-Honeycrisp.jpg" title = "사과입니다.!!!" width="250px;">
  </body>
</html>
```

The above simple html file contains title tag with some paragraph as text. When run the page, the title is getting truncated and showing ellipsis as ...
How to show the complete text in the browser tab title?

I am using the angular 13 to set the title from the component as:
https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Comment: It is always going to get truncated. You can animate the title to start scrolling to display the whole text

Comment: how can we do that?

Comment: Not sure you can, displaying the title in a browser tab is the job os the browser, not the job of your app. You can only provide what you want to show, and that's it.

Comment: @Billy I found this [Article](https://www.cssscript.com/animate-page-title-browser-tab/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show the whole paragraph in title of a webpage. Normally only 25-30 characters are visible. So try to concise your title.

You can use meta tag to put a paragraph, which will help in SEO and will be for bots.

Comment: You can always animate the title

Comment: yes, you can. But in my opinion animation of scrolling of title is not smooth so it doesn't look that good.

Comment: use of metatag will show the title without truncation?